# Calculating probability with multiple winners and multiple accounts

Tags: probability

Suppose that a giveaway is happening on Twitter. $50$ winners are to be chosen once it finishes. To enter the giveaway, you must like the giveaway post. Currently there are $2300$ likes on the post. If you own $27$ Twitter accounts and like the post on each account, what are the chances that at least one account wins the giveaway?

The way I attempted it was to do $\frac{1}{2300} * 50 * 27$. This gets around $58$% of winning, but this seems too high to be correct.

Comment: $\displaystyle 1 - \left[\frac{\binom{2300}{50}}{\binom{2327}{50}}\right].$

Answer (score 1):

$$P(\text{at least one win}) = 1 - P(\text{no wins}) = 1 - P(X = 0)$$
where $X$ is a [hypergeometric distribution](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). Plugging in the parameters to the probability mass function gives
$$
=1 - \frac{\left(\begin{array}{l}
27 \\
0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
2327-27 \\
50
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
2327 \\
50
\end{array}\right)}
$$
$$
=1-\frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
2300 \\
50
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
2327 \\
50
\end{array}\right)}
$$
which simply equals $0.446$